# Save data from a text file into an array in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to read a text file in python. The first line of the file is just the name of the file and rest each line of the file contains a real number. I am new to python and trying to parse the file and save the numbers in a single array (ignoring the first line). Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    next(f) # discard the first line
    l = [int(line) for line in f]   # save numbers to a list
```

---

Read the first n lines, use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice),

```
import itertools 

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines_gen =  itertools.islice(f, 1, num_lines) # start from 1,  read num_lines
    l = [int(line) for line in lines_gen]
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine. However, After 501 lines of data, there is another line which is a string. Can I in any way just create an array of numbers which starts from line 2 and ends at line 500?

Comment: You don't really need the `rstrip()` call, `int` can handle trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Arya, try this, `l = [int(line) for line in f.readlines[2:501]]`

Comment: @Arya: You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to only process a portion of the file.

Comment: Slicing the `readlines()` result is a pretty inefficient way to do it, and hard-coding the line number containing a string with a magic number is nearly guaranteed to cause problems later on.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, many thanks. I just edited the answer.

Comment: You can give `islice()` an additional _start_ argument which would make it also skip the first line (so it wouldn't be necessary to use `next()`).

Comment: @martineau, thx, I just updated my answer. U improved my answer a lot.

Comment: @sparkandshine isslice() works and the problem is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Open it, skip the first line, and map the rest to integers (with a `list()` call to save it in memory - only necessary if you plan to go through it more than once, or mutate it).

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    next(f)
    data = list(map(int, f))
```

Comment: This is a very pythonic way! I suggest using this one. Note that this use of next is for python 3. for python 2, use f. readline()

Comment: @silvio: `next(f)` would work fine in Python 2, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
your_array = []
with open('arrayfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()  # skip first line
    for number in f:
        your_array.append(int(number))
```